# How to populate columns one after another dynamically by iterating over list in primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a requirement to populate the list of available options column by column.
    I have a list of regions in the left panel and right panel with 4 columns and
    10 rows. Now if I select a region 'X' having 12 options, first column should
    be populated fully and second column only 2 rows. I couldn't find any useful link
    helping me to figure out a way to solve my problem. Is there any way to achieve
    this in JSF or Primefaces.

Comment: Answer: Yes, there is.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/

Comment: Thanks Mr.J4mes. I can get the region specific options to be displayed on ajax call but my problem is how to represent the data in the format I have asked in question. Could you please try to suggest a way for the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

Because you do not state that the columns/rows must show specific model attributes e.g., `id`, `name`, `max`, `min` or whatever, I assume that you just want to enumerate a model in your two dimensional table. I don't think there is a JSF/Primefaces way to do this. My solution would be to preprocess the data before returning it to the view. Thats also the moment when you have the most control over your model. Of course it is not the most elegant way, but I cannot see another when using JSF/PF.
Processing:

1.) Just append an 'empty' Model element after each row (i used `String`s), until the max colums is reached

2.) Do that for every row which was '1 more item' in the row, e.g. 22 items -> first 2 rows need 1 empty item less

3.) Fill up the other rows with empty items

4.) Done. Use standard JSF/PF UI components.

This small *bad/ugly/hacked* code snipped might get you the idea of preprocessing.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;



public class Test {

    static int columns = 4;
    static int rows = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
            populate(strings);
            int before = strings.size();
            process(strings);
            int after = strings.size();
            print(before, after, strings);
        }
    }

    private static void print(int before, int after, List<String> strings) {
        System.out.println(before + " ================ " + after);
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
                int index = row * columns + col;
                System.out.print(strings.get(index) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("=====================");
    }

    private static void process(List<String> strings) {
      int regionsSize = strings.size();

      // how much rows have to be filled with 1 empty item less
      int rowsWithMoreToAdd = regionsSize % rows;
      // where we need to insert the empty item
      int index = (int) Math.floor(regionsSize / rows);
      String emptyOption = "   ";

      // insert one empty item less in these rows
      for (int i = 0; i < rowsWithMoreToAdd; i++) {
          // insert empty items until the last column
          for (int ii = index + 1; ii < columns; ii++) {
              strings.add(ii + i * columns, emptyOption);
          }
      }

      // insert empty items in thes rows
      for (int i = rowsWithMoreToAdd; i < rows; i++) {
          // insert empty items until the last column
          for (int ii = index; ii < columns; ii++) {
              strings.add(i * columns + ii, emptyOption);
          }
      }
    }

    private static void populate(List<String> strings) {
        int random = new Random().nextInt(rows * columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < random; i++) {
            strings.add("bla");
        }
    }



}
```

Some example outputs:

```
13 ================ 40
bla bla         
bla bla         
bla bla         
bla             
bla             
bla             
bla             
bla             
bla             
bla             

24 ================ 40
bla bla bla     
bla bla bla     
bla bla bla     
bla bla bla     
bla bla         
bla bla         
bla bla         
bla bla         
bla bla         
bla bla         

34 ================ 40
bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla     
bla bla bla     
bla bla bla     
bla bla bla     
bla bla bla     
bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 2):

this is my proposal:

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:panelGrid columns="#{testBean2.model.cols}">
                <c:forEach var="elem" items="#{testBean2.model.list}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{elem}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton action="#{testBean2.select12}" update="@form" value="select 12" />
            <p:commandButton action="#{testBean2.select24}" update="@form" value="select 24" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

TestBean2.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean2 implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private TransposedTableModel<String> model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        select12();
    }

    public void select12()
    {
        model = new TransposedTableModel<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            model.add("value " + (i + 1));
        }
    }

    public void select24()
    {
        model = new TransposedTableModel<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            model.add("value " + (i + 1));
        }
    }

    public TransposedTableModel<String> getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
}
```

TransposedTableModel.java

```
public class TransposedTableModel<T>
{
    private final List<T>[] model;
    private int index;

    public TransposedTableModel()
    {
        model = new ArrayList[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            model[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        index = 0;
    }

    public void add(T value)
    {
        model[index++ % 10].add(value);
    }

    public List<T> getList()
    {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int cols = model[0].size();

        list.addAll(model[0]);

        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            List<T> row = model[i];

            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                list.add(j < row.size() ? row.get(j) : null);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public int getCols()
    {
        return model[0].size();
    }
}
```